# Wicket - position of div tag changes on applying setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag true

Tags: html, position, wicket-1.5

I have a div tag in my html page which acts as a placeholder for a panel.

In my java code, whenever I apply setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true) on the panel, the position of my div tag in the html automatically changes to top-left, whereas the original position of my div was bottom-right as I set in my CSS stylesheet.

What should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to set the flag to true by calling Component.setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true)?
After all, it seems that setting the flag modifies a style information of the enclosing  block tag.

Can you provide the actually produced html code? Press  in your browser to see the html source code.
Maybe it will look like

```
<div id="something" class="xy">
    ...
</div>
```

As I see, you have **three options** after inspecting the produced div tag:
**a)** Don't set the flag Component.setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true). You can control the visibility of your panel implementation by an override

```
@Override
protected void onConfigure() {
    super.onConfigure();

    boolean visible = ...; // evaluate the state
    setVisible(visible);
}
```

Check http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.5/ for further details of the Component class. (A Panel is a Component.)
**b)** Modify the style information produced by Wicket by something like:

```
panel.add(new AttributeModifier("class", "styledPanel");
```

or more conservative:

```
panel.add(new AttributeAppender("class", "styledPanel");
```

You might but have to update the "style" information.

**c)** Update your CSS stylesheet by reflecting the style information produced by Wicket for this div tag.

Actually, a combination of b) and c) will lead you to the goal. You have to check the produced html code of your panel in the browser.
As far as I am concerned, I would prefer solution a).

Comment: I don't know how it happened but the problem got resolved on its own. Maybe I did something wrong before. thanx anyways, I learnt something new from you.